# Bash array not filling in loop reading from file

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm trying to fill an array with the lines in a file in bash. I do not understand what is happening here:

```
balter@exahead1:~$ declare -a a
balter@exahead1:~$ cat t.txt
a b
c d
e f
g h
balter@exahead1:~$ cat t.txt | while read -r line; do echo $line; a=("${a[@]}" "$line"); echo "$i: ${a[$i]}"; echo "${a[@]}"; ((i++)); done
a b
0: a b
a b
c d
1: c d
a b c d
e f
2: e f
a b c d e f
g h
3: g h
a b c d e f g h
balter@exahead1:~$ echo "${a[@]}"

balter@exahead1:~$
```

**EDIT:**
Apparently it "works" if I redirect the file in rather than pipe it:

```
balter@exahead1:~$ while read -r line; do echo $line; a=("${a[@]}" "$line"); echo "$i: ${a[$i]}"; echo "${a[@]}"; ((i++)); done < t.txt
a b
0: a b
a b
c d
1: c d
a b c d
e f
2: e f
a b c d e f
g h
3: g h
a b c d e f g h
balter@exahead1:~$ echo "${a[@]}"
a b c d e f g h
balter@exahead1:~$
```

**EDIT 2**
@anubhava--what version of `bash` would I need? I tried your suggestion, and although we have `mapfile` it did not "work".

```
balter@exahead1:~$ bash --version
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)   
balter@exahead1:~$ unset a
balter@exahead1:~$ a=()
balter@exahead1:~$ mapfile -t a < t.txt
balter@exahead1:~$ echo "${a[@]}"

balter@exahead1:~$
```

Neither did the 2nd method:

```
balter@exahead1:~$ unset a
balter@exahead1:~$ a=()
balter@exahead1:~$ echo "${a[@]}"

balter@exahead1:~$
balter@exahead1:~$ while IFS= read -r line; do a+=("$line"); done < t.txt
balter@exahead1:~$ echo "${a[@]}"

balter@exahead1:~$
```

**EDIT 3**

Both of the above methods "work" on my Mac running *El Capitan*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use builtin `mapfile` for this:

```
mapfile -t arr < file
```

If you are on older BASH version then you can use `while` loop like this:

```
arr=()

while IFS= read -r line; do
   arr+=("$line")
done < file
```

Comment: Aha! We crossed. But you did teach me two things. (1) I've never heard of mapfile. (2) I did not know you could append arrays like that. What version of `bash` do I need? See my edits above.

Comment: `mapfile` was added in bash 4

Comment: My system has bash 4.2.46, but it did not fill the array using the method you suggested. However, my Mac is running 4.4.12, and it does "work".

Comment: I have BASH 4.3.46 and `mapfile` works. [See this link](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/mapfile) Some version of bash had bugs